# how do i check for specific values from a dropdown list using this.value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html-select, getelementbyid

I have a dropdown select list with about 10 options connected with a hidden div which supposed to be displayed when only any of specific 3 options being chosen using javascript code

```
document.getElementById('item').addEventListener('change', function () {
var style = (this.value == "661056067" or this.value == "571855424") ? 
'table-row' : 'none';
document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = style;
});
```

I tried the code showed above as I wanted this.value function to be equal to more than one value but it didn't work. So whats the right way to make ot work. Kindly be noted I am not good at all with javascript.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Logical operators in javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `or` use `||`

```
document.getElementById('item').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var style = (this.value == "661056067" || this.value == "571855424") ? 
    'table-row' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = style;
});
```

You can also use `includes`.

```
document.getElementById('item').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var style = ["661056067", "571855424"].includes(this.value) ? 'table-row' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = style;
});
```

Comment: I have another question if you please. Inside this hidden div I have input fields which must be filled upon being shown, so how to set the attribute required using the above suggested code. Your code here above works, thank you very much.

Comment: Get all the children(which are input element) of hidden div,  iterate over it and add the attribute `required` to each input element.

Comment: I already did this but I found the other options which I don't need to show the hidden div for them, I will not be able to submit them (submit button is not active). So I was thinking to set attribute required only for the input elements when the parent div will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

use `||` operator

```
var style = (this.value == "661056067" || this.value == "571855424") ?  'table-row' : 'none';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way you can implement this. It takes advantage of [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const hiddenEl = document.querySelector('#hiddenEl');
const handler = e => {
  hiddenEl.style.display = ['661056067', '571855424'].includes(e.target.value) ? 'block' : 'none';
};
document.querySelector('#selectEl').addEventListener('change', handler);
```

```css
#hiddenEl {
  display: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<label for="pet-select">Choose a pet:</label>

<select id="selectEl">
  <option value="1">Hide hidden 1</option>
  <option value="661056067">Show hidden 1</option>
  <option value="2">Hide hidden 2</option>
  <option value="3">Hide hidden 3</option>
  <option value="571855424">Show hidden 2</option>
  <option value="4">Hide hidden 4</option>
</select>

<div id="hiddenEl"><h2>Here is the hidden div!</h2></div>
```